# Large Rails suite architecture: combine three apps into one container app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, architecture

Our Rails suite is comprised of three independent Rails apps:

1. JSON API (Rails app)
2. Admin dashboard (Rails app)
3. Shared data models (Rails engine)

Both the API and Admin dashboard require the shared data models engine in their Gemfiles. All models and custom classes are stored in the engine, and both apps make heavy use of the shared components. The API lives on one Heroku server, and the Admin dashboard lives on another separate Heroku server (two separate Heroku apps). Each use their own respective Postgres databases. All three apps have their own GIT repos.

The API database stores information pertinent to our public users, and the Admin database stores mostly statistical information for admin eyes only.

A caveat of the setup is that the Admin dashboard app has direct access to the API database, and vice-versa. I understand that this is bad practice and may not seem to make sense, but there was a reason for this (mainly because the Admin dashboard needed to access all records of certain API tables, and the use of a custom API to communicate over the wire was not feasible). A similar reason exists for the API-to-Admin database communication.

This setup works for our purposes, nothing is broken, and resources are allocated efficiently. However, productivity is beginning to suffer due to the slow and uncomfortable development process. An example: a change to the API is required. Chances are that the shared models engine needs a change and therefore a feature branch is needed in both repos. After committing and pushing, the Admin dashboard now contains an old version of the models engine (is behind by one patch version). The problem lies in trying to coordinate all three Rails apps, when only one app needs a change. Another problem is migrations. Since the models engine contains two different database connections, I must create the migration once in the models engine then create it again in the appropriate app (API or Admin).

My ideal setup would involve one large Rails container app with separate engines contained within. The separate engines would be: API, Admin, Models. Also, I’m beginning to think that using only one database might make things easier. I would also like to keep the API on its own server instance, and the Admin on a separate server. The reason for this is that the API is public facing (communicates with a public iOS app) and the Admin is used mainly as a CMS and reporting engine.

I am looking for solutions and advice from experience managing similar Rails / Heroku architectures. Specific questions:

1. Should I attempt to combine the three Rails apps into one container
   app and use the engine approach?
2. Should I attempt to combine the two
   databases into one database?
3. Is it possible to have one Rails
   container app, and allocate different servers to different engines?
4. If I should keep all apps separate, is their an easier and more
   productive way to implement new features and fixes on a daily basis?